# Query that will select a timeframe from specific date to today

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm having issues in my WHERE clause selecting data from a specific day to today's date. The day/time format in my date column is '7/2/2020 3:12:08 PM'.

I've tested a couple options but keep getting this error - 'literal does not match format string'.

Any idea's of how I can select all data from March 1, 2020 to current date?

Thanks!

Comment: what is your db name?

Comment: Fix your database so the column is stored using a native format rather than as a string!

Comment: @Fahmi call the table 'TABLE1' and the date column 'DATE'

Comment: @dmd7, what is your database ?? is it MySql, Sql Server, Oracle ? Which One?

Comment: @Fahmi It is Oracle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle date columns are not strings, they are exactly in date datatype, so you don't need to convert/cast it. Just use simple date literals:
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Literals.html#GUID-8F4B3F82-8821-4071-84D6-FBBA21C05AC1

```
select * from table where your_date_columg >= date'2015-12-31'
```

or with to_date function for your string:

```
select * from table 
where
 your_date_columg >= to_date('2019-11-25 13:57:52',
                             'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: I just changed date and time to do not confuse